# Pure virtual function called! when using GLES20.glLinkProgram

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I´m getting this error when linking my program. I don't know what it means. It fails to link on my adreno moto g, but works fine on an emulated nexus 6 on genymotion.

What do you think could be wrong? Both shaders compile fine.

This is the exact error I get:

```
03-29 19:16:22.203  17087-17087/com.manu.juegos.half_hero E/libc++abi﹕ Pure virtual function called!
03-29 19:16:22.203  17087-17087/com.manu.juegos.half_hero A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 17087 (uegos.half_hero)
```

This is the function that calls to the link routine:

```
public static int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
    int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
    if (vertexShader == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
    if (pixelShader == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    if (program != 0) {
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        GlProgram.checkGLError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
        GlProgram.checkGLError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
        int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
        if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ");
            Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
            program = 0;
        }
    }

    GlProgram.checkGLError(" - post ShaderManager.createProgram - ");

    return program;
}
```

The program flow breaks after the glLinkProgram call and I cant even verify the result of the linking process

This is my vertex shader code:

```
#define numLights x // x is replaced by the number of lights in compile time
#pragma glsl

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

// matrices we'll need
uniform mat4 inversedTrasposedModelViewMatrix; 
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

// other uniforms, constant or data we are going to use

struct LightSourceParameters {
    mediump vec3 ambient; 
    mediump vec3 lightColor;
    mediump vec4 position;  
    mediump float spotExponent; 
    mediump float spotCutoff; // (range: [0.0,90.0], 180.0)
    mediump vec3 spotDirection;
    mediump float constantAttenuation; 
    mediump float linearAttenuation; 
    mediump float quadraticAttenuation; 
};
uniform LightSourceParameters LightSource[numLights];

// out parameters to fragment shader: varyings      
varying vec3 outNormal;
varying vec2 outTextCoord;
varying vec3 outViewVector;
varying vec3 outLightVector[numLights];

void calculateLightVectors(in vec4 in_position);

void main(){

    // Calculate view-space position coordinate
    vec4 P = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);

    // Calculate the normal in view-space
    outNormal = vec3(inversedTrasposedModelViewMatrix * vec4(normal ,0.0));

    // Calculate the view vector in view-space space coordinate
    outViewVector = -P.xyz;

    // Assign the texture coordinate
    outTextCoord = texCoord;

    // Calculate clip-space position of each vertex

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * P;
    //gl_Position = P;
    // gl_Position = vec4(position,1.0);
    calculateLightVectors(P);
    gl_PointSize = 50.0f;
    //gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(1.0);
} 

void calculateLightVectors(vec4 P){
    // Calculate light vector for all light source
    for (int indexLightVector = 0; indexLightVector < numLights; indexLightVector++){
        /* Si no es ambiental: la unica luz que no lleva asociada vector */
        if ((length(LightSource[indexLightVector].ambient) == 0.0) /* no ambiental */
            && (LightSource[indexLightVector].position.w != 0.0)){ /* no directional */

            /* La luz es o point o spotLight */
            vec4 lightPosition = LightSource[indexLightVector].position;
            outLightVector[indexLightVector] = (vec3(modelViewMatrix * lightPosition) - P.xyz);

        }
        else if (length(LightSource[indexLightVector].ambient) == 0.0) { /* no ambiental */
            /* La luz es directional: position es un vector,
             * lo transformamos con inversedTransposedModelViewMatrix
             * y lo negamos para que vaya desde el punto a la luz y no al rev�s
             */
            outLightVector[indexLightVector] = - vec3(inversedTrasposedModelViewMatrix*LightSource[indexLightVector].position);

        }

    }
}
```

This is my fragment shader code:

```
#define numLights x
#pragma glsl

precision mediump float;

struct LightSourceParameters {
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 lightColor;
    vec4 position;
    float spotExponent;
    float spotCutoff; // (range: [0.0,90.0], 180.0)
    vec3 spotDirection;
    float constantAttenuation;
    float linearAttenuation;
    float quadraticAttenuation;
};
uniform LightSourceParameters LightSource[numLights];

struct MaterialParameters {
    vec4 emission;
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    float shininess;
    bool hasDiffuseTexture;
    bool hasSpecularTexture;
    bool hasEmissionTexture;
    bool hasAmbientTexture;
    bool hasNormalTexture;

    sampler2D emissionTexture;

    sampler2D diffuseTexture;
    sampler2D specularTexture;

    sampler2D ambientTexture;
    sampler2D normalTexture;
};
uniform MaterialParameters Material;

varying vec2 outTextCoord;
varying vec3 outNormal;
varying vec3 outViewVector;
varying vec3 outLightVector[numLights];


/* Declaramos cabecera de funcion, necesaria para que GLSL no diga que la funcion no existe, al definirse despues de main */

vec4 computeLight(in LightSourceParameters lightSource, in vec3 normal, in vec3 lightVector, in vec3 halfVector);
vec4 computeEmissionLight();


void main(){

    // Normalize the incoming vectors
    highp vec3 normal = normalize(outNormal);
    highp vec3 viewVector = normalize(outViewVector);

    // BACKFACE CULLING:
    //if (length(normal) == 0.0) discard;


    float NdotVV = dot(normal,viewVector);


    //if (NdotVV <= 0.0) discard;


    // normalize lightvector, compute half vectors and lights
    highp vec4 totalColorLighting = vec4(0.0);


    for (int indexComputeLights = 0; indexComputeLights <  numLights; indexComputeLights++){

        LightSourceParameters light = LightSource[indexComputeLights];

        highp vec3 currentLightVector = vec3(0.0);
        highp vec3 currentHalfVector = vec3(0.0);


        if (length(light.ambient) == 0.0 ){ /* no es ambiental, que no tienen vector ni half vector */

            currentLightVector = outLightVector[indexComputeLights]; // normalizamos posteriormente, para poder obtener la distancia a la luz del m�dulo de este vector
            currentHalfVector = normalize(outLightVector[indexComputeLights] + outViewVector);
        }
        else {
            // nothing
        }



    /* Si la luz es ambiental, halfVector y lightVector son
     * indefinidos para esa luz, pero da igual porque no son
     * utilizados en el algoritmo que calcula las luces
     */


        totalColorLighting = totalColorLighting + computeLight(light, normal, currentLightVector, currentHalfVector);
        totalColorLighting = clamp(totalColorLighting,vec4(0.0),vec4(1.0));

    }


    totalColorLighting = totalColorLighting + computeEmissionLight();
    totalColorLighting = clamp(totalColorLighting, 0.0, 1.0);

    /* Devolvemos el color de fragmento calculado para almacenarlo en el framebuffer */
 gl_FragColor = totalColorLighting;

}

vec4 computeEmissionLight(){

    vec4 totalEmissionColorLighting = vec4(0.0);
    if ((length(vec3(Material.emission)) != 0.0) || (Material.hasEmissionTexture)) {
        /* El material tiene un termino emisivo, es decir, emite luz. Lo andimos al total de color calculado */
        if (!Material.hasEmissionTexture) {
            totalEmissionColorLighting = Material.emission;

        }
        else {
            totalEmissionColorLighting = texture2D(Material.emissionTexture, outTextCoord);
            totalEmissionColorLighting.rgb *= totalEmissionColorLighting.a;

        }

    }

    return totalEmissionColorLighting;
}

vec4 computeLight(in LightSourceParameters lightSource,
                in vec3 normal, in vec3 lightVector, in vec3 halfVector){

    vec3 normalizedLightVector = normalize(lightVector);

    float attenuation = 1.0; // no attenuation
    highp vec4 totalLightingColor = vec4(0.0); // no color

    if (length(lightSource.ambient) > 0.0) { // es luz ambiente
        vec4 ambientalTerm = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
        if (!Material.hasAmbientTexture){
            ambientalTerm =  Material.ambient;

        }
        else {
            ambientalTerm = texture2D(Material.ambientTexture, outTextCoord);
            ambientalTerm.rgb *= ambientalTerm.a;
        }
        totalLightingColor = vec4(lightSource.ambient, 1.0) * ambientalTerm;
//totalLightingColor = vec4(0.0);

    }
    else { // Is not ambiental light


        // BACKLIGHT CULLING:

        float NdotLV = dot(normal, normalizedLightVector);
        if (NdotLV < 0.0 ) { // light source in the wrong side
            return vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
        }



        if (lightSource.position.w == 0.0) { // es un vector, por lo tanto es una luz direccional
            attenuation = 1.0; // no attenuation

        }
        else { // Is a point light or a spot light (LIGHTVECTOR EXPRESA UN VECTOR DESDE GL_FRAGCOORD HASTA LA LUZ, NO LA DIRECCION DE LA LUZ A SECAS): SACAMOS DISTANCIAS
            float distanceToLight = length(lightVector);

            attenuation = lightSource.constantAttenuation / ((1.0+lightSource.linearAttenuation*distanceToLight)*(1.0+lightSource.quadraticAttenuation*distanceToLight*distanceToLight));


            if (lightSource.spotCutoff <= 90.0){ /* Is a spot light */


                vec3 spotDirection = normalize(lightSource.spotDirection);
                float clampedCosine = max(0.0, dot(-normalizedLightVector, spotDirection));

                if (clampedCosine < cos(radians(lightSource.spotCutoff))){ /* outside the spotlight cone */
                    attenuation = 0.0; /* full attenuation */
                }
                else { /* inside the spotlight cone */
                    attenuation = attenuation * pow(clampedCosine, lightSource.spotExponent);
                }
            }
        }

        // Calculo de los terminos de color: diffuso y especular
        vec4 diffuseReflection = vec4(0.0);
        vec4 diffuseMaterialTerm = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); /* El canal difuso será NO opaco y negro hasta que se sobreescriban sus datos */
        if (!Material.hasDiffuseTexture) { /* El canal difuso no tiene textura */
            diffuseMaterialTerm =  Material.diffuse;
        }
        else {
            diffuseMaterialTerm = texture2D(Material.diffuseTexture, outTextCoord);
        }



        diffuseReflection = attenuation * vec4(lightSource.lightColor, 1.0) * diffuseMaterialTerm * max(0.0, NdotLV);
        if (Material.hasDiffuseTexture){ // premultiplicado por alpha en bitmapfactory de android
            diffuseReflection.rgb *= diffuseMaterialTerm.a;
        }
        vec4 specularReflection = vec4(0.0);


        // LIGHT SOURCE IS ALWAYS IN THE RIGHT SIDE DUE TO BACKLIGHT CULLING

            highp float NdotHV = max(dot(normal, halfVector), 0.0); /* Normal-dot-halfvector */

            vec4 specularMaterialTerm = vec4 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); /* El canal especular será NO opaco y negro hasta que se sobreescriban sus datos */
            if (!Material.hasSpecularTexture){
                specularMaterialTerm = Material.specular;
            }
            else {
                specularMaterialTerm = texture2D(Material.specularTexture, outTextCoord);
            }

            specularReflection = attenuation * pow(NdotHV, (Material.shininess)) * vec4(lightSource.lightColor, 1.0) * specularMaterialTerm;
            if (Material.hasSpecularTexture){ // premultiplicado por alpha en bitmapfactory de android
                specularReflection.rgb *= specularMaterialTerm.a;
            }

        totalLightingColor = diffuseReflection + specularReflection;

    }
    return totalLightingColor;
    //return clamp(totalLightingColor,vec4(0.0),vec4(1.0));
}
```

I don't know what I did. I just deleted some coments in the computeEmisionLight (in fragment shader) and now is linking fine. Please tell me if you know what did the difference. This is the new computeEmisionLight code:

```
vec4 computeEmissionLight(){

    vec4 totalEmissionColorLighting = vec4(0.0);
    if ((length(vec3(Material.emission)) != 0.0) || (Material.hasEmissionTexture)) {
        /* El material tiene un termino emisivo, es decir, emite luz. Lo andimos al total de color calculado */
        if (!Material.hasEmissionTexture) {
            totalEmissionColorLighting = Material.emission;
        }
        else {
            totalEmissionColorLighting = texture2D(Material.emissionTexture, outTextCoord);
            totalEmissionColorLighting.rgb *= totalEmissionColorLighting.a;

            // discard;
            // texture2D(material.diffuseTexture, outTextCoord);
        }
    }
    return totalEmissionColorLighting;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what I did. I just deleted some coments in the computeEmisionLight (in fragment shader) and now is linking fine. Please tell me if you know what did the difference. I add the new function code to the first post.